# Cobertura Coverage Report Image

Tags: tomcat, hudson, cobertura

Does anybody know where Cobertura sticks it's coverage report image?

The url to my image is:
http://ContinualTests/746/cobertura/graph

When I dig down on my box that is running tomcat/hudson I find

tomcat6/.hudson/jobs/XX/builds/746 but I don't see the graph.  Is the image getting generate on the fly?  Seems like something that would be generated once and reused.

Erik

Comment: Unless the host name is wrong, it is a bit hard to view an image from your internal network... Can you upload it to the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant code is [here](http://fisheye4.atlassian.com/browse/hudson/trunk/hudson/plugins/cobertura/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/cobertura/CoberturaBuildAction.java?r=19512#l223).   It appears to use some browser caching, but otherwise the chart is generated on the fly every time, so you won't find it on disk.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  

So what would you recommend if we want to display our Cobertura reports at various project milestone releases?  Meaning I want to have a static report (not even in Hudson) displayed on our download page for the release/milestone?

Comment: I think using 'wget' or 'curl' or something similar to copy the generated image into your report location would work nicely.